# T-SQL - Get rows as column (Pivot not working)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have data like below sample.

```
VariableName    variableValue   
row_count       5326    
FileName        [OrderFeed_20160406.tsv]
TableName       OrderFeed
TableID         1
row_count       788 
FileName        [CategoryFeed_20160406.tsv]
TableName       Category
TableID         2
row_count       224
FileName        [ItemFeed_20160406.tsv]
TableName       Item
TableID         3
row_count       991
FileName        [ContactFeed_20160406.tsv]
TableName       Contact
TableID         4
```

I want show that data like  below:

```
row_count | FileName                  | TableName |TableID
5326      |[OrderFeed_20160406.tsv]   |OrderFeed  |1
788       |[CategoryFeed_20160406.tsv]|Category   |2
```

When I use PIVOT , It is work but order of data is changing. I mean ,if [OrderFeed_20160406.tsv] has 5326 rows and TableId of it is 1 in real but after pivot [OrderFeed_20160406.tsv]  has 788 rows and get different TableID als.

My sample pivot code is below :

```
select  row_count,
[FileName],
TableID,
TableName from (
 select VariableName , VariableValue,row_number() over(partition by VariableName
                        order by VariableValue) seq
 from DailyLogs   
 ) d 
 PIVOT (count(VariableValue) for variableName in (  row_count,
FileName,
TableID,
TableName))
piv;
```

Comment: This is a strange database design. How do you know which rows are connected to eachother?

Comment: Agree with @Tobb, your target answer should be your table design.

Comment: unfortunatly there is no connection between each rows. It is log table , and yes it is very strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (row_no INT IDENTITY(1,1), variableName NVARCHAR(200)
                ,variableValue NVARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO @TABLE
SELECT * FROM DailyLogs

SELECT  [row_count],[FileName],[TableName],[TableID]
FROM    (
    SELECT variableName,variableValue,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY variableName ORDER BY row_no) AS ROWNO FROM @TABLE
    ) T PIVOT( MAX(VariableValue) FOR 
            variableName IN ([FileName],[row_count],[TableID],[TableName])) PIV
ORDER BY [TableID]

Result is :

row_count   FileName                    TableName   TableID
5326        [OrderFeed_20160406.tsv]    OrderFeed   1
788         [CategoryFeed_20160406.tsv] Category    2
224         [ItemFeed_20160406.tsv]     Item        3
991         [ContactFeed_20160406.tsv]  Contact     4
```

Comment: Query modified, result also included , plz check